# Rails 3 - Creating a New Record not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Scenario: I have an EventsController with a new event record. Depending on what I want to do with that event/record, I may need to create a new Ticket Record.

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
```

In my EventController, I have a method for eg.

```
def do_something
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  # I would like to create a Ticket record here
end
```

I have tried the following in my method:

```
@ticket = Ticket.new(:event_id => @event.id)
    @ticket.ticket_name = @event.event_name
    @ticket.ticket_quantity = 1000
    @ticket.ticket_price = 0
    @ticket.save
```

The above does absolutely nothing. I don't even get any errors in my log.
as well as this:

```
Ticket.create!(
  :event_id       => @event.id,
  :ticket_name         => @event.event_name,
  :ticket_quantity  => 1000,
  :ticket_price => 0 )
```

For this one: I get:
*ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Event is not allowed to create Tickets):*

I'm not sure if I'm even doing in the right place or not.
Thanks

Comment: I should note, that I tried to create both of those 2 egs in the do_something method in my EventsController in case it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 4):

With your current model associations the correct way to create a new `Ticket` is through the `Event` object. Like this:

```
@ticket = @event.tickets.create(:ticket_name => @event.event_name, 
                                :ticket_quantity  => 1000,
                                :ticket_price => 0)
```

Note that you don't have to specify the `event_id`.

For a more in depth explanation take a look at [active record associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

On a side note, in your `Event` controller if you do `save!` that should throw errors for you as well. Adding the bang `!` will do a validation and if it fails, throw an error.

Comment: So tried this in my EventsController
`def my_method
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])

    @event.tickets.create(
      :ticket_name => @event.event_name,
      :ticket_quantity => 1000,
      :ticket_price => 0 )
    if @event.save!
`


And I get this error in my log:
_ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Tickets base Event is not allowed to create Tickets)_

Comment: I do have a TicketsController that handles creating Tickets on their own. Just passing the event id in the params for the association and that works fine.
But if theres a certain condition on a particular Event, I would like to create a Ticket without having to use a Forms For field and the controller. Just have it all create at once.

Answer (score 0):

Execute

```
rails console
```

in your command line, try to create Ticket object there and see what output you get, then post it here, it would help to figure out what's the problem.

Also you can look at

```
@ticket.errors
```

in your debugger to see if there are any.

Comment: Something like this?
`>> @e = Event.find(:last)
=> #<Event id: 40016, event_name: "Testing A Free Event", ...>
>> @ticket = Ticket.new(:event_id => @e.id)
=> #<Ticket id: nil, event_id: 40016, order_id: nil, ticket_name: nil, ticket_price: nil, ticket_quantity: nil, currency: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> @ticket.ticket_name = 'Test Ticket'
=> "Test Ticket"
>> @ticket.save
=> false
>> @ticket.errors
=> #<OrderedHash {:base=>["Event is not allowed to create Tickets"]}>`

Comment: Do you have some validations in those models, are you using some plugins or gems? Please list them, beacouse this is first time i see error like this ;)